# MVC5 Code First One-To-One Relationship Error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, relationship, one-to-one

I'm trying to do one-one relationship for MVC5 codefirst. [I've looked this page](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) and did exactly same things but I've got an error.

Here is my classes and context:

Product:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Display order
    /// </summary>
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public string TitleBackgroundColor { get; set; }
    public virtual TblClass TblClass { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Price> Prices { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductFeature> ProductFeatures { get; set; }
}
```

TblClass:

```
 public class TblClass
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Product")]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public int ClassOrder { get; set; }
}
```

DBContext:

```
   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Role>()
            .HasMany<UserProfile>(r => r.UserProfiles)
            .WithMany(u => u.Roles)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable("webpages_UsersInRoles");
                m.MapLeftKey("RoleId");
                m.MapRightKey("UserId");
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity<TblClass>()
            .HasKey(c => c.ProductId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
        .HasOptional(f => f.TblClass)
        .WithRequired(s => s.Product)
        .Map(t => t.MapKey("ProductId"));
    }
```

And when I try to run 'update-database -verbose' I've got this error:

> The navigation property 'Product' declared on type 'YazililarGaranti.Domain.Entities.TblClass' has been configured with conflicting foreign keys.

Comment: Try chaning   .HasOptional(f => f.TblClass) to  .HasMany(f => f.TblClass) or delete that line.

Comment: deleting the line: Error
changing it to hasmany: Error

Comment: Nope problem is not resolved, I've changed screenshots to actual codes in my post. Not about my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to use `.Map(t => t.MapKey("ProductId")` when making an 1:1 relationship. This should work:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    //... other properties
    public virtual TblClass TblClass { get; set; }
    //... other properties
}

public class TblClass
{
    //[Key, ForeignKey("Product")] <-- remove these attributes
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
    //.. other properties
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public int ClassOrder { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    //other mappings

    modelBuilder.Entity<TblClass>()
        .HasKey(c => c.ProductId); 

    modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
        .HasKey(c => c.ProductId); //consider to use database generated option

    //modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().Property(t => t.ProductId) 
        //.HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
        .HasOptional(f => f.TblClass)
        .WithRequired(s => s.Product);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I've an otrher error when I apply your solution: Multiple identity columns specified for table 'Products'. Only one identity column per table is allowed.

Comment: You have set the `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity` more than one time. Take a look at your code, ensure that it is configured only once . Perhaps it may be solved if you remove `modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().Property(t => t.ProductId) .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);` from the `OnModelCreating` method

Comment: did you remove the `[Key]` attribute from `TblClass`? You either set `[Key]` attribute in the class, or `modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasKey(c => c.ProductId);` in the `OnModelCreating` method. You can't use both

Comment: the codes are exactly what you write. Did you try codes in your visual studio?

Comment: No I didn't. Just give me a minute, I'll try this right now

Comment: I tried the new project and it worked! But there no other properties and classes in the new project. Just Product and TblClass and just relationship.
So there is something in my code but what?

Comment: I tried here, and it worked fine too. Copy all of your classes (including the `OnModelCreating` method) into a new pastebin http://pastebin.com/. Then, send me the link and I'll take a look

Comment: I fixed the problem by reseting migrations. I deleted migration_history and migration folder in my project and I had to delete database also. However I have data in my database so I took the data backup first. Then I deleted the tables and created again and add migrations and add data. So at last update-database -verbose works! This is insanity.. I just wanted to add one-to-one relationship between two tables. And look! I had to do a million things. I am really angry. 
Anyways... thanks for help Fabio